# Iframes and React.js - How to embed a youtube video into my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to understand how to include a youtube embed into my app.

```js
import React from "react";
import Pageheader from "react-bootstrap/lib/Pageheader";
import ResponsiveEmbed from "react-bootstrap/lib/ResponsiveEmbed";
import Grid from "react-bootstrap/lib/Grid";

export default class Services extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="services">
        <Pageheader justified>
          About us
          <small>
            M2 Consulting is Bringing Small Businesses to the Agile century
          </small>
          <ResponsiveEmbed a16by9>
            <embed src="https://youtu.be/uC9VtVnuPD0" />
          </ResponsiveEmbed>
        </Pageheader>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is what I have at the moment.

I've tried a few different methods of getting to properly display but have found using, for example, the embed code from youtube to create multiple errors. I'm trying to replicate this website and how it displays its embedded video.

https://moodmap.app/

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can just use an `iframe` element to achieve this. There is no need to depend on yet another `npm` package.

```html
<iframe
  src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/E7wJTI-1dvQ'
  frameborder='0'
  allow='autoplay; encrypted-media'
  allowfullscreen
  title='video'
/>
```

By the way, if you are wondering why the `embed URL` looks like it looks, you can just go to an arbitrary `Youtube video`, click on `Share` and then you immediately see that we just need to append `/embed/:videoId` `Youtube's` base `URL`.

Comment: So the only difference between the HTML YouTube gives you when you press 'share', is the capitalisation of `allowFullScreen` and `frameBorder`. Fix that, and you're done.

Comment: Hello there, youtuber.

Comment: one change I needed: `export const YoutubeEmbed = (embedId) => 
  embedId && ( <iframe ... />);`

Comment: jk that didn't fix my problem. for some reason it only works when I hard code the embedId. It's trying to fetch `embed/[Object object]`

Comment: For completenes sake, turns out it's a problem with my code that generates the `embedId`. I wish you could edit comments so I didn't have to triple post, but alas.

Answer (score 8):

You can use react component [react-youtube](https://github.com/troybetz/react-youtube)

Comment: Brilliant. Now how would I integrate it with this code?

Comment: https://github.com/CookPete/react-player works with many different providers and provides responsive styling.

Answer (score 0):

If your app downloads a list of videos and you want to play the video upon clicking on the video card:

```
 {videos.map((video, idx) => {
          return (
            <Link href={`/video/${video.id}`}>
              <a>
                <Card
                  id={idx}
                  imgUrl={video.imgUrl}
                  size={size}
                  shouldScale={shouldScale}
                />
              </a>
            </Link>
          );
        })}
```

When clicked, you would be redirected to `/video/${video.id}`. in this page you get the dynamic `video.id`

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const videoId = router.query.videoId;
```

Play the video:

```
 <iframe
        id="ytplayer"
        className={}
        type="text/html"
        width="100%"
        height="360"
        src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}?autoplay=0&origin=http://example.com&controls=0&rel=1`}
        frameBorder="0"
      ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me using Material-UI's CardMedia

```
<CardMedia component="iframe" 
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NpEaa2P7qZI"
  sx={{
    aspectRatio: "16/9",
  }}
/>
```

Aspect Ratio
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio