# How to load and play a Youtube video in React

Tags: reactjs, iframe, youtube

Currently I am trying to build an app that should include a YouTube link `"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=IEDEtZ4UVtI"`. So the first attempt to run this is O`<video className="video" src="https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=IEDEtZ4UVtI"></video>`, but as you might see it would not work as it should suppose to be. What are the other options. Keep in mind I don't have any embedded links in my API, so the first YouTube link you see only one that I should use.

Answer (score 9):

Earlier it was possible to embed Youtube videos like this:

```html
<video controls="true">
    <source src="www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEDEtZ4UVtI" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

But not anymore.

The only option is to use the usual `iframe` embedding, which works nicely with React apps. You just need to use the Youtube video ID from the link you have and use it in the embed link `https://youtube.com/embed/${youtubeID}?autoplay=0`.

```js
const [youtubeID] = useState('IEDEtZ4UVtI')

[...]

<iframe className='video'
        title='Youtube player'
        sandbox='allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-presentation'
        src={`https://youtube.com/embed/${youtubeID}?autoplay=0`}>
</iframe>
```

Comment: I get: `www.youtube.com refused to connect.`

Comment: @FotiosTsakiris do you have another error? I suppose where you are trying to embed youtube is not an HTTPS domain (localhost?)

Comment: Hi @theDavidBarton, yes it's not HTTPS, it's `http://localhost:3000/`. But how am I supposed to test this, if I cannot run it on localhost? And no, I didn't have another error.

Comment: I suggest you to create a standalone question about the issue. I've tried to reproduce it, but it works fine on localhost and [in production](https://thedavidbarton.github.io/react-examples/#/youtube-iframe) for me with the above approach. if you want to here you can clone my example project and try it in your localhost if it differs from your implementation and if works: https://github.com/theDavidBarton/react-examples

Comment: Here is the good solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/54503528/5783617

Answer (score 7):

There is an easy way;

First of all install:

```
$ npm install react-youtube
```

import:

```
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';
```

and the usage-

```
<YouTube videoId="IEDEtZ4UVtI"/>
```

You can see more options for react-youtube  [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube)

Comment: I get: `An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: CpjzL59dfF8l6ILI)`

Comment: be carefull while using this package , 
`Event.path` is deprecated and will be removed. Please use `Event.composedPath()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-player`

`npm i react-player`

```js
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player/youtube'

 <ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IpYJjVw6wjU&ab_channel=fotios' />
```

[docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player)

Answer (score 0):

The `videoId` property of the YouTube component should be the actual ID of the YouTube video, not the full URL.